# read and set the value of variable from log file to KSH shell script

Tags: variables, redirect, ksh

I have a log file (which is on output from running a python script)
The log file has the list of variables that I want to pass to a shell script. How do I accomplish this

Example
Log file has the following content. It has the variables x, y, z

Contents of file `example.log`:

```
2016-06-07 15:28:12.874 INFO x = (10, 11, 12)
2016-06-07 15:28:12.874 INFO y = case when id =1 then gr8 else ok end
2016-06-07 15:28:12.874 INFO z = 2016-06-07
```

I want the shell script to read the variables and use in the shell program

Sample shell
shell.ksh

## Assign variables

```
var1 = read_value_x from example.log
var2 = read_value_y from example.log
```

Is there a generic shell function that  I can use to read the log and parse the variable values

Thanks
PMV

Comment: which part of the log file do you want to set in var1,var2 ? An example o/p will be always helpful. Also post what you have tried, while asking a question.

Comment: the expressions that have " = " in the log is the list of variables . I want to read the first line and set it to var1, 2nd line and set it to var2... I did not try any code as I'm a newbie to shell scripting. I know regex can be used in this context, but not sure how to loop them/ create a generic function

Comment: How generic do you want? If you can massage the text into a piece of shell script, you can `eval` that, but the general consensus is usually that you shouldn't.

Comment: i will always have a log file with the setup like this. I want to pass the log file as input and set the variables in shell

Comment: I use KSH (Korn Shell). I'm not sure about bash (which version of bash I have). Ae arrays handled better in bash?

Comment: `bash`, `ksh`, and `zsh` all support arrays, but there are differences, both with respect to array-access syntax itself and the builtins (such as `read` and `readarray` / `mapfile`) that can create arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you can do it reasonably efficiently in `ksh`, for smallish files:

```sh
# Read into variables $var1, $var2, ...
n=0
while IFS='=' read -r unused value; do
  typeset "var$((++n))=${value# }"
done < example.log

# Enumerate the variables created.
# Equivalent to: `echo "$var1"`, `echo "$var2"`, ...
for (( i = 1; i <= n; ++i)); do
  eval echo \"\$'var'$i\"
done
```

Comment: how do i add the connection var1 = x (10,11,12)? ..i am thinking that in the shell if use combination of eval and loop to assign these variables so that the shell will assume these values..

Answer (score 0):

Read the log file, use regex to get the value after `=` on each line and assign to a variable in a loop.

Comment: is there any sample code or key word search i can do to get this function?

Answer (score 0):

```
var1=$(awk -F " = " '$1 ~ /[x]$/' < file.log)
var2=$(awk -F " = " '$1 ~ /[y]$/' < file.log)
```

The ***awk*** utility command above will use the delimiter `" = "` and using regex we check whether `$1` is having `x` or `y` at the end; if it does, we set the value to relevant variable.

In case you want to set the 2nd part in variable

```
var1=$(awk -F " = " '$1 ~ /[x]$/{print $2}' < file.log)
var2=$(awk -F " = " '$1 ~ /[y]$/{print $2}' < file.log)
```